# How to export logo in illustrator?

Tags: logo, export, shadows

I would like to export a logo from Illustrator, but various parts of the logo are being separated in the export panel. I tried to group and unite the different parts of the logo before exporting them. Unfortunatelly, it did not work. The logo has two shadows and it is one letter.

[image]

Comment: Most likely you want to remove the part on the right, reduce the artboard size to just the logo, then export it to an image format like .jpg

Comment: Hey Zach, thanks for your answer. By the way your talk in Poland is very interesting.